# implicit instantiation of undefined template "std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >"

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors

I am learning C++ and following a tutorial, but got issue with building the code in the starter code.

Here's the source code file where this error is being thrown.

```
#include "linux_parser.h"

#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::stof;
using std::string;
using std::to_string;
using std::vector;

// DONE: An example of how to read data from the filesystem
string LinuxParser::OperatingSystem() {
  string line;
  string key;
  string value;
  std::ifstream filestream(kOSPath);
  if (filestream.is_open()) {
    while (std::getline(filestream, line)) {
      std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ' ', '_');
      std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), '=', ' ');
      std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), '"', ' ');
      std::istringstream linestream(line);
      while (linestream >> key >> value) {
        if (key == "PRETTY_NAME") {
          std::replace(value.begin(), value.end(), '_', ' ');
          return value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

Following is the error thrown when I run `make build` locally on mac Catalina.

```
Scanning dependencies of target monitor
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/monitor.dir/src/format.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/monitor.dir/src/linux_parser.cpp.o
/Users/Documents/github/cpp/src/linux_parser.cpp:25:26: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'
      std::istringstream linestream(line);
                         ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:133:32: note: template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_istringstream;
                               ^
/Users/Documents/github/cpp/src/linux_parser.cpp:44:24: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::__1::basic_istringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'
    std::istringstream linestream(line);
                       ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:133:32: note: template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_istringstream;
                               ^
2 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/monitor.dir/src/linux_parser.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/monitor.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `#include <sstream>` in order to use `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Worked great! I thought it was `istream`. Thanks @brian

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same error while using the [std::stringstream](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/) class. Add this header file:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to clang, which occasionally is restrictive with implicite template instantation. Could not make following code run, with whatever header includes, while the default instantations (byte=char) are accepted by the compiler.

```
#include <sstream>

// typedef char byte;
typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef std::basic_string<byte> ByteArray;

typedef std::basic_istringstream<byte> bistringstream;



int main()
{
    const ByteArray a = (const byte*)"hello";
    bistringstream d(a);
    ByteArray b;
    d >> b;

    return 0;
}
```